# POST to a REST API from a wordpress form

Tags: api, http-api, plugin-json-api

I dont want to use a REST API to publish to wordpress.

I want to create a form on a wordpress page which will send a POST to an external REST API. Users will put in their information, and perhaps upload a file. When the press "submit" I want this information to be sent to a REST API on a different server (not wordpress).

Are there any plugins that allow this? Has anyone done this? Of course, I might run into troubles with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

It looks like I want to do the reverse of this: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/
Instead of making a REST API for wordpress, I want to make wordpress communicate send a POST to an external REST API when a user presses a button on a form.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a plugin that does it in a general way; for the most part, you'll need to build something custom for each specific API you intend to communicate with.

For your purposes, the key function will be `wp_remote_post()`, which is a wrapper for the POST method of WP's HTTP class. (Use this instead of making manual cURL requests, because WP_Http has all kinds of fallbacks for different modes of HTTP transport.) Here's a nice introduction: http://yoast.com/wp-best-practice/wordpress-http-api/ Same origin policies generally only apply to browsers. `wp_remote_post()` and its ilk are fired on the server.

Sending data is pretty easy - just put an array into the 'body' of your `wp_remote_post()` call. The tricky part is always authentication - does the API server expect a pre-registered key, or some sort of oAuth handoff, or what. If it's as simple as a shared key, you can just pass it as part of the `'body'` payload.

Comment: This page has been intentionally deleted. too bad that you didn't write an example so it can keep in time

Comment: Does anyone could helps on this? I m looking at it too. to modify wpForm submit button post to external API

Comment: There is documentation on `wp_remote_post` on WP's website, but I don't think it's enough. It's a start. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/

Comment: There's also this wordpress.stackexchange question and answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49022/post-to-a-rest-api-from-a-wordpress-form